# ListBox items are added twice instead of once

Tags: c#, listbox

I'm developing an universal windows app and when I add an item to a listbox it appears twice with no errors

Here is the code

```
private async void btnNew_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    listBox.Items.Add(nameBox.Text);
    string type = comboBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
    URL url = new URL();
    url.type = type;
    url.name = nameBox.Text;
    url.info = infoBox.Text;
    url.url = urlBox.Text;
    url.isProtected = isProtectedSwitch.IsOn;
    await url.saveToXML();
    infoBox.Text = "";
    nameBox.Text = "";
    urlBox.Text = "";
    comboBox.SelectedIndex = -1;
}
```

And if needed:

```
public async Task saveToXML()
{
    //Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\Link");
    URL newURL = new URL();
    newURL.type = type;
    newURL.name = name;
    newURL.info = info;
    newURL.url = url;
    newURL.isProtected = isProtected;
    newURL.amountOfClicks = amountOfClicks;
    StorageFile file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(@"Link\" + newURL.name + ".xml", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
    Stream fileStream = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync();
    DataContractSerializer serialize = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(URL));
    serialize.WriteObject(fileStream, newURL);
}
```

Comment: why are you doing everything twice, either pass it directly to saveToXML or in Click

Comment: There's nothing here that would add items twice. Do you perhaps have some code in events for `comboBox`?

Comment: The simplest explanation is that you subscribed this Click event handler twice.  Like once in the XAML and again in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Cannot see any issue in the code you have provided.

Probably you are not clearing exiting `listBox.Items` before adding Items. Make sure you `listBox.Items.Clear()` prior adding new list of items.

Answer (score 0):

Clean listbox before you add items.

```
listBox.Items.Clear();
```

It is posible, that you double click this button, so code fires twice.